# Execute code after callback ngResource

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs, angularjs-rails

I've got function inside my controller for `ngResource` create

```
app.controller 'CalculationsCtrl', ($scope, Calculation)->

  $scope.save = ()->
    $scope.busy = true
    Calculation.create($scope.calculation,
      (successResult)->
        console.log ("sucess")
      , (failResult)->
        console.log ("failrue")

    console.log("code after callbacks")
    $scope.busy = false
```

I want to execute code below `console.log("code after callbacks")` after `.create` callbacks are executed.

I tried to use `.then` but it seems ngResource doesn't support it.

`Calculation.create(...).then is not a function`.

What is the equivalence of `.then` for ngResource?

Comment: why not just add your code below `console.log("code after callbacks")` ?

Comment: @levi it might executed before callbacks. Callbacks are asynchronus.

Comment: @levi Possible output is:

"code after callbacks"
"success"

when code in ran

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Calculation.create(...).then is not a function.` is returned because callbacks return `"strings"` (from `console.log`).

Callback need o return server response.

app.controller 'CalculationsCtrl', ($scope, Calculation)->

```
  $scope.save = ()->
    $scope.busy = true
    Calculation.create($scope.calculation,
      (successResult)->
        console.log ("sucess")
        successResult
      , (failResult)->
        console.log ("failrue")
        failResult
    ).$promise.then(
       function(succes){$scope...}, 
       function(fail){$scope...}
     )
```

Answer (score 0):

The `$resource` instance (in your case `Calculation`) has a property `$promise` on which you can use `.then` as usual:

```
Calculation.create($scope.calculation).then(function (response) {
    ...
});
```

The last example in the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource#credit-card-resource) also shows you how it's done.

Answer (score 0):

Angular $resource returns a promise which you can use .then on.

```
Calculation.create().$promise.then( function( response ) {
    console.log("success");
}, function( error ) {
    console.log("error");
);
```